# Uploaded PHP files not running on Amazon cloud ,while files created there are running well

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have deployed my PHP web app on Amazon Ec2 cloud , but my files are not running ,because my my files's are uploed using ec-user account while if i create a file there using root it can run easily.
i have changed the owner and group of all uploaded files to root , but then also server response is

The website encountered an error while retrieving **mydns/index.php** It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

while if i run another file which i create there using putty then it runs perfectly.

Please help me if u think a some configuration is required there
I have deployed the website there inside /var/www/html/somefolder/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unix is case sensitive while Windows is not when i am referring any files in case sensitively the  PHP gives error in Unix only so, to make it woking I need to make all paths and file referencing like
various include ,require,src and action varible and methods case sensitive.

Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

check the permissions of a .php file which is working and one which isn't with ls -l. I believe the permissions need to be 744.

Comment: They don't the executable bit set: 644

Comment: permissions of both the files are -rw-r--r-- which is 644

Comment: should i also set the same permissions for directories like directory of images,stylesheets,js files etc?

Comment: Is it possible some caching is going on, either in your browser, on your website, or on amazon's side that is causing you to not see changes? Try clearing the history, removing cookies, doing a forced reload in your browser. ** Directory permissions are not important (unless it is your web root), however, are you sure there are no errors on your web pages causing them to not display correctly? I sometimes run the php interpreter from the command line to debug my website when it is not displaying.

Comment: ya there are no issues in the website becasue it is running well locally. t think i should restart the amazon instance